# How to increase Swap size on Docker for windows

Tags: docker, memory, swap

I'm using Linux containers on Docker for windows.

Because of using gcc inside one of the containers I need to assign more than 4GB swap file to this container.

Previously, I used swapon to add more swap files but this stopped working with error:

`swapon: failed operation not permitted`

All I found is that it's not recommended to add own swap files to containers and only host swap file should be used.

But, in Docker for Windows, Swap file is limited to 4GB and I didn't find a way how to increase it:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/pdTPdFt/Docker-Desktop-2020-02-20-18-21-07.png]

Is there any command line or Docker-engine json param how to set it for example to 8GB?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json` directly,
like `"SwapMiB": 8192`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this file. It seems that changing it to 8192 really change the swap size (based on swapon command inside the VM).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the advanced settings tab were not visible from the docker desktop setup. Hence i had to modify directly in the settings.json file in the path mentioned below.

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json
```

and manually restarted the docker, to take this in to effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you did an WSL 2 backend install of docker (which is now the default option), you need to create a `.wslconfig` file in your user directory.

The file should have the following structure:

```
[wsl2]
memory=19GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 
swap=110GB
```

Windows documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig

Comment: That worked for me, thank you. Restart is needed after changes to that file